# Azure User Impersonation Setup Between Two Applications

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity

I am currently working between two applications in Azure, which need to communicate with each other. There exists an application, which needs to call the APIs to another application. I have set up user impersonation in my App Registration, where I have access to the API endpoint (application). The main application (calling API) is retrieving a token through Microsoft's graph API using my client ID / client secret. I then use the access token generated to call the API endpoint. The problem is that the endpoint directs the request to the Microsoft Sign in page. How can I avoid hitting the Microsoft Sign in Page.

The flow of API:

1. User logs in to the first application (using Microsoft login)
2. The application retrieves a token from my application created in Azure (no backend code) and calls the graph API to retrieve a token
3. The (original application) uses the token generated to call the endpoint.
4. The request is sent to the sign-in page.

Comment: I think you're asking the token to the wrong resource. This can be the reason, another possible problem can be a miss implicit grant flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to propagate the delegated user identity and permissions through the request chain.For the middle-tier service to make authenticated requests to the downstream service, it needs to secure an access token from the Microsoft identity platform, on behalf of the user.

When you send Service-to-service access token request, set the `scope` with your API's scope. Then you will get the access token for API and not hit login page again.

[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow).